# vips thumbnail transparent issue for svg image

Tags: vips

I have one transparent SVG image, I am trying to generate the thumbnail of that image. It generates a thumbnail of the image properly, but it removes the transparency of the image and adds a black background to the image. I want to generate thumbnail without losing the transparency of the image.

**Note - The same problem with jpg and jpeg images also, but I added white background to the image in svg case it's not make the transparent background**
**I am using PHP vips library.**

Here is my code for that

```
$im = Vips\Image::thumbnail($filename, 180, ['height' => 225, 'size' => 'both']);
$alpha = $im->hasAlpha();
if($alpha) {
    $im = $im->flatten(['background' => [255, 255, 255]]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just write to a format that supports transparency, like PNG.

For example:

```php
$im = Vips\Image::thumbnail("x.svg", 180, ['height' => 225, 'size' => 'both']);
$im->WriteToFile("x.png");
```

WEBP, GIF, HEIC, AVIF, TIFF etc. also support transparency. JPEG does not.